# Android java canvas surfaceview , the object is getting a value where it less or more than the set minimum value

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview

i am using android studio for the development a game which is a snake game , i am using Surfaceview.  my problem is that im getting value which is less than 1  from the min value i set.

here is my code for the update method where the  validation of the snake object hits the corner and should draw the object to the opposite side.

numlockswide = 30

numblockshigh = 16

minhigh = 2

maxhigh = numblocks high

```
 public void updateSnake() {


//every 100 ms or 1s the score increment
        long elapse = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
        if (elapse > speed) {


//checks if hits the border so it could come from the opposite border
            //north and south

            if (snakeX[0] > numblocksWide) {
                snakeX[0] = 0;
            } else if (snakeX[0] < 0) {
                snakeX[0] = numblocksWide;
            }

            //east west

            if(snakeY[0] > maxHigh){
                snakeY[0] = minHigh;
            }else if(snakeY[0] < minHigh){
                snakeY[0] = maxHigh;
            }


            for (int i = snakeLength; i > 0; i--) {

//                System.out.println("snake[i] = " + i + " bx loc " + snakeX[i] + " by loc " + snakeY[i]);
                snakeX[i] = snakeX[i - 1];

                snakeY[i] = snakeY[i - 1];
//                System.out.println("snake[i] = " + i + " nbx loc " + snakeX[i] + " nby loc " + snakeY[i]);

            }

            switch (currentDirection) {
                case EAST:

                    snakeX[0]++;
                    angle = 0;
                    break;
                case WEST:
                    snakeX[0]--;
                    angle = 180;
                    break;
                case SOUTH:
                    snakeY[0]++;
                    angle = 90;
                    break;
                case NORTH:
                    snakeY[0]--;
                    angle = 270;
                    break;
            }

            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

    }
```

problem is i alread set that the minimum value if its from left right direction is 0 but i am getting a value of -1 which is why i cant eat the apple object that is in the corner/edge of the borders. this is my firsttime using surfaceview and canvas ,would anyone please help me with this bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert 0 in snakeX[0] = 0;

```
 if (snakeX[0] > numblocksWide) {
            ***snakeX[0] = 0;***
        } else if (snakeX[0] < 0) {
            snakeX[0] = numblocksWide;
        }
...
```

then here you decreased to -1

```
case WEST:
                snakeX[0]--;
                angle = 180;
                break;
```

To tackle the problem bring your condition to the end of your function:

```
if (snakeX[0] > numblocksWide) {
            snakeX[0] = 0;
        } else if (snakeX[0] < 0) {
            snakeX[0] = numblocksWide;
        }
```

It will probably be OK:

```
public void updateSnake() {


    //every 100 ms or 1s the score increment
    long elapse = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
    if (elapse > speed) {





        for (int i = snakeLength; i > 0; i--) {

            //                System.out.println("snake[i] = " + i + " bx loc " + snakeX[i] + " by loc " + snakeY[i]);
            snakeX[i] = snakeX[i - 1];

            snakeY[i] = snakeY[i - 1];
            //                System.out.println("snake[i] = " + i + " nbx loc " + snakeX[i] + " nby loc " + snakeY[i]);

        }

        switch (currentDirection) {
            case EAST:

                snakeX[0]++;
                angle = 0;
                break;
            case WEST:
                snakeX[0]--;
                angle = 180;
                break;
            case SOUTH:
                snakeY[0]++;
                angle = 90;
                break;
            case NORTH:
                snakeY[0]--;
                angle = 270;
                break;
        }

        //checks if hits the border so it could come from the opposite border
        //north and south

        if (snakeX[0] > numblocksWide) {
            snakeX[0] = 0;
        } else if (snakeX[0] < 0) {
            snakeX[0] = numblocksWide;
        }

        //east west

        if(snakeY[0] > maxHigh){
            snakeY[0] = minHigh;
        }else if(snakeY[0] < minHigh){
            snakeY[0] = maxHigh;
        }

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you sir its fixed , i didnt notice that it was my function that was mis placed , i always thought it was something that involves the view and canvas ,,...